# How to query with Check CONSTRAINT when using exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge view with a lot of account cost tables.Those tables have check CONSTRAINT.They are built every month.
Like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[book_cost_1204] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [CKT_book_cost_1204] 
CHECK (([billdate] >= '2012-04-01' and [billdate] < '2012-05-01'))
```

If I use this query :

```
select * from book_cost where billdate >= '2017-11-01'
```

It will just use two tables:book_cost_1711 and book_cost_1712.

But if I query another table then using exists to query this view like this:

```
select * from (another table having account info) a
 where exists (select top 1 from book_cost where billdate>=a.billdate)
```

With checking statistics io ,I find that it queried all tables.

Why it don't use check?

I used cursor to check every row, but it's too slow.I also want to use proc,but 
is seems that where can't use exec?

How to solve it?

Comment: Is this a partitioned view, where `billdate` is part of the primary key? Are all the check constraints trusted and have mutually exclusive ranges? Upload your actual execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add the link to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman yes,they have mutually exclusive ranges.Every of them just has a single month's data.The query plan is too big .It is over 2mb.It has more than 30 thousand rows.

Comment: `billdate` is not a part of primary key.But there is a Clustered index on `billdate`.

Comment: I've seen plans over 2MB uploaded to the site. Did you try it?

Comment: This is check one row like that [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkzuhAlbG)

Comment: @DanGuzman another while query like this [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rk4e20lWG) .In this plan billdate is all after 2017-03-01.

Comment: When I use this while query and ths rowcount is more than 20,it was out of memory. lol. May be  I should use the first statement,just exist,don't think too much.When solve the variate it don't know,it always choose table scan.

Comment: I can't get the second link. The first query includes a missing index suggestion for gdsid, shopid, billdate. It seems the actual index used is on gdsid alone or perhaps gdsid and some other column. Note that you will get static table elimination with the literal. With a join, dynamic elimination may or may not happened depending on the plan shape.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160362/discussion-between-dan-guzman-and-mopetite).